# how to create a vertical calendar in php

Tags: php

How to create a calendar in php..
By vertical, i mean all the dates of a month will be one after another.. 1 row will contain 1 date of a month.. Actually there will be four column.One column will contain the date of a month and other three columns are for three different rooms (each room will show their availability status-booked or not against the specific date for that particular month..)
I am trying but not able to create like this..
Any help/suggestion/link will be appreciated..

Thanks..

Comment: What have you tried and in what way did it not work? This isn't a question so much as a description of a (very basic, so basic that no tutorial explaining it will exist) program...

Comment: In other words, "Can you give me teh codez"

Answer (score 2):

at first, you need the number of days for the current month

```
$num_days = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $desired_month, 1, $desired_year));
```

For explanation see [PHP Manual: Date](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)

Next step will be, to go through all the days and create the four columns

```
    for ($index = 1; $index <= $num_days; $index++) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $index . "." . $desired_month . "." . $desired_year . "</td>
        <td>col2</td><td>col3</td><td>col4</td></tr>";
}
```

This should serve your need.